# How to have changes to the field type in a form datasource refresh in Xpages?

Tags: xpages, datasource

I have a form datasource that had a Rich Text field ("Photo") in it.  I changed the field type of the Rich Text field to Rich Text Lite (still named "Photo") on the form, but the field type in the "document1" datasource in Xpages still says it's field type Rich Text.  How can I get this datasource to refresh from the underlying form?

MJ

Comment: The field is still a rich text item. On your form in the Notes client it's just represented as rich text lite but content is still saved as rich text

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten make this an answer, so mike can credit you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field is still a rich text item. On your form in the Notes client it's just represented as rich text lite but content is still saved as rich text

Comment: Thank you for the education.  I had no idea.